Is there a way to configure VSCode / remote-ssh extension such that you can have root access to the instance?
I'm seeking a solution to streamline file manipulation (Create, Read, Update, Delete) through the Visual Studio Code GUI while SSH'd into a remote instance with limited permissions. Currently, I'm forced to use Linux commands with sudo for each file operation, which is time-consuming and inefficient.
Ideally, I'd like to:

Connect to the instance as the root user
Be prompted for the root password only once per session
Have full access to edit, save, and manage files directly through the VS Code interface

This would significantly enhance my workflow and productivity. Despite extensive online research, I haven't found a solution to this problem.
Has anyone successfully implemented such a setup or can suggest a secure approach to achieve this? Any guidance or alternative solutions would be greatly appreciated.
